# Nonsense error using a Python Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a Python script to deploy in Google Cloud Functions, in order to manage the creation of new documents on my Firestore database (Firestore triggers). I am deploying the function in the Google Cloud console, not locally. The functions is implemented correctly without any error. However, when I create a new document, an error occurs that is related with Flask, which is nosense as my Python script does not require Flask. This is all the setup of the function : [image] [image] [image], this is the error : [image], and this is the Firestore section, document, and value created : [image]. Why am I having this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not sharing anything useful to help. Check the logs and share that. How can you asure this is implemented correctly? And don't share code as a screenshot. Learn how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok thank you @Puteri. Next time the problem will not be repeated